# CSS Transition not working in only Mozila firefox browser

Tags: css, firefox, css-transitions, css-animations

Trying to fix this CSS3 Transition for *Mozila firefox*, it's working perfectly in *Chrome and Opera* but not working in *Mozila firefox 35.0.1+* . I have also applied `-moz-keyframes` on CSS.

*CSS:*

```
/******************
* Bounce in Left *
*******************/
@-webkit-keyframes bounceInLeft {
    0% {
        opacity: 0;
        -webkit-transform: translateX(-1000px);
    }

    80% {
        -webkit-transform: translateX(-10px);
    }

    100% {
        -webkit-transform: translateX(0);
    }
}

@-moz-keyframes bounceInLeft {
    0% {
        opacity: 0;
        -moz-transform: translateX(-1000px);
    }

    80% {
        -moz-transform: translateX(-10px);
    }

    100% {
        -moz-transform: translateX(0);
    }
}

@-o-keyframes bounceInLeft {
    0% {
        opacity: 0;
        -o-transform: translateX(-1000px);
    }

    80% {
        -o-transform: translateX(-10px);
    }

    100% {
        -o-transform: translateX(0);
    }
}

@keyframes bounceInLeft {
    0% {
        opacity: 0;
        transform: translateX(-1000px);
        -moz-transform: translateX(-1000px);
    }

    80% {
        transform: translateX(-10px);
        -moz-transform: translateX(-10px);
    }

    100% {
        transform: translateX(0);
        -moz-transform: translateX(0px);
    }
}

.animated.bounceInLeft {
    -webkit-animation-name: bounceInLeft;
    -moz-animation-name: bounceInLeft;
    -o-animation-name: bounceInLeft;
    animation-name: bounceInLeft;
}

/****************
* bounceInRight *
****************/
@-webkit-keyframes bounceInRight {
    0% {
        opacity: 0;
        -webkit-transform: translateX(1000px);
    }

    80% {
        -webkit-transform: translateX(10px);
    }

    100% {
        -webkit-transform: translateX(0);
    }
}

@-moz-keyframes bounceInRight {
    0% {
        opacity: 0;
        -moz-transform: translateX(1000px);
    }

    80% {
        -moz-transform: translateX(10px);
    }

    100% {
        -moz-transform: translateX(0);
    }
}

@-o-keyframes bounceInRight {
    0% {
        opacity: 0;
        -o-transform: translateX(1000px);
    }

    80% {
        -o-transform: translateX(10px);
    }

    100% {
        -o-transform: translateX(0);
    }
}

@keyframes bounceInRight {
    0% {
        opacity: 0;
        transform: translateX(1000px);
    }

    80% {
        transform: translateX(10px);
    }

    100% {
        transform: translateX(0);
    }
}

.animated.bounceInRight {
    -webkit-animation-name: bounceInRight;
    -moz-animation-name: bounceInRight;
    -o-animation-name: bounceInRight;
    animation-name: bounceInRight;
}

/* Description */
#headslide p {
-webkit-animation-name:bounceInRight;
-moz-animation-name:bounceInRight;
-o-animation-name:bounceInRight;
animation-name:bounceInRight;
-webkit-animation-duration:1s;
-moz-animation-duration:1s;
animation-duration:1s;
-moz-animation-fill-mode:both;
animation-fill-mode:both;
box-shadow:0 1px 4px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
-webkit-box-shadow:0 1px 4px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
-moz-box-shadow:0 1px 4px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
-o-box-shadow:0 1px 4px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
-ms-box-shadow:0 1px 4px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);

margin:0;
}

/* Title */
#headslide h3 {
-webkit-animation-name:bounceInLeft;
-moz-animation-name:bounceInLeft;
-o-animation-name:bounceInLeft;
animation-name:bounceInLeft;
-webkit-animation-duration:1s;
-moz-animation-duration:1s;
animation-duration:1s;
-moz-animation-fill-mode:both;
animation-fill-mode:both;

background: #fff;
font-size: 110%;
line-height: 1.4;
padding: 1% 2%;
margin: 0;
font-weight:normal;
text-transform:uppercase;
}
```

*HTML:*

```
<div id="headslide">
<ul>
<li class="post-content">
<div class="slidshow-thumbnail">
<a href="#"><img src="wallpaper.jpg" height="260" width="350"/></a>
</div>
<span class="content-margin">
<p>Description on top.</p>
<h3><a href="#">Title on bottom</a></h3>
</span>
</li>
<li class="post-content">
<div class="slidshow-thumbnail">
<a href="#"><img src="picture.jpg" height="260" width="350"/></a>
</div>
<span class="content-margin">
<p>Description on top.</p>
<h3><a href="#">Title on bottom</a></h3>
</span>
</li>
</ul>
<div class="pager"></div>
</div>
```

There are two type effects `bounceInLeft` (*Applied on Title on bottom*) and `bounceInRight` (*applied on description on top*). On Chrome it's working perfectly but not working on Mozila firefox. This Slider has fade transition by default, so it show fade transition on firefox and my bounceInLeft/bounceInRight keyframes works only on Chrome, Opera.

*How to fix this?*

Please See this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/g44ttyve/5/) >> on *Mozila firefox 35.0.1+* and on latest Chrome.
Thanks.

Comment: do you know the the https://daneden.github.io/animate.css/ library ?

Comment: Yes, i have got those css from Animate.CSS, but it's not working on Firefox on this slider.

Comment: Ashesh 's deleted answer was right: remove the -moz stuff from the unprefixed version. I can't fiddle anything cause I'm from the phone, if it still doesn't work, please notify me tomorrow

Comment: @Andrea Ligios i have tried it, but it still doesn't work.

Comment: Ok, it is not enough. +1 because there is actually a different behavior between the two browsers. You seems to not understand however where to put the prefixes: remember that the UNprefixed version MUST be always put at the end. There were at least 5-6 properties with the unprefixed before or in the middle of the prefixed ones. The solution is still to find, but start from this version with the prefixed/unprefixed stuff corrected: http://jsfiddle.net/g44ttyve/7/

Comment: Thanks for your information. but how to use it on fiddle?